# What does it mean that EOS tokens will become fixed/frozen?

Tags: tokens, token-distribution

I've purchased some EOS/ETH assets via Binance.

However I've got some concerns regarding what I read at [eos.io page](https://eos.io/instructions) about distribution schedule that:

> The distribution schedule comprises of one (1) 120-hour period commencing June 26, 2017 at 13:00 UTC, followed by three hundred fifty (350) consecutive 23-hour periods commencing July 1, 2017 13:00:00 UTC. **Within 23 hours after the end of the final period on June 1, 2018 at 22:59:59 UTC, all EOS Tokens will become fixed (ie. frozen) and will be non-transferrable on the Ethereum blockchain.**

Does it mean I won't be able to trade and sell my tokens back to Ethereum (ETH)? Or I shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: The other question is specific to Binance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will come a time when EOS will have to take a snapshot of all Ethereum wallets that are registered before launching their mainnet. To ensure that there are no new EOS tokens being purchased and to limit trading of tokens owned by speculators, it is important to freeze all tokens for a smooth swap.

It is not clear at this moment if exchanges like Binance will continue to let speculators trade EOS. Unlikely, IMO.

However, Binance claims to support EOS mainnet token swap, in which case you need not take action but trust the exchange to do it for you. https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001649171-Binance-Will-Support-EOS-MainNet-Token-Swap

But if your tokens are in an exchange that does not support the swap, then it should concern you. It's best if your tokens are held in an Ethereum wallet which is 'registered' to an EOS wallet for which you own the private keys. You will find multiple tutorials on how to register your EOS token on the internet.